# KafkaConsumer timeouts when using a proper group.id

Tags: java, apache-kafka

Read this piece of code:

```
String clientId = "some argument" + System.currentTimeMillis();

Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("group.id", clientId); // Yes, we know NOW that this makes no sense.
props.put("client.id", clientId);
// + bootstrap.servers, key.deserializer, value.deserializer, SPECIFIC_AVRO_READER_CONFIG
// + schema.registry.url and security.protocol. 
// Their specific values doesn't matter.

KafkaConsumer<String, T> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, T>(props);
consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList("some topic"));

// Inside some timer callback:
final ConsumerRecords<String, T> consumerRecords = consumer.poll(0);

if (consumerRecords.count() > 0) {
      // do something with consumerRecords
      consumer_.commitAsync(); // I'm not sure why this is here, but makes no sense to me.
}
```

Ok. The problem is that we were not using the group.id properly (because we didn't understand how consumer groups work). Now we have chage `group.id` to point to something that persists across sessions, so that after rebooting the consumer we consume everything we missed while we weren't looking, but now we get "timeouts":

- We have actually 2 instances of the consumer above. Everything equal except they point to two different topics (with two different schemas and value types). The group.id is the same for both instances. Each 100 ms, we call poll(0) for the first instance, and then poll(0) for the second one, and then we wait another 100ms and repeat.
- Both topics as of today have only 1 partition each, in case that matters here.
- The first instance works fine: it polls at each cycle, returns almost immediately, and if there's new records, we consume them fine.
- The second instance, for the second topic, using the "improper" group.id worked fine as well, but after changing it for a "proper" group.id, the second instance blocks inside poll for five minutes, and then returns, without launching an exception or anything.

If we replace the "proper" group.id to an "improper" one back, then both consumers work fine again.

What does actually "poll(0)" do? I guess that, besides fetching the topic metadata and such in the first call, it does a single request to the cluster asking for new offsets, and if there's nothing new, then return. Otherwise, fetch the new stuff.

But, what part of the `poll` behaviour could explain that using a "shared" and "reusable" group.id changes the behaviour of poll, but only for one of the consumers and not the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, solved. The problem is that you cannot have two consumers from the same group subscribed to different topics: https://github.com/tulios/kafkajs/issues/1040

Although there's conversations going on and it looks like it can be subject to change. I haven't quite got yet what's the problem, but it seems related with partition assignment.